# Sandbox test account for Square is not working for JPY?

Tags: payment-gateway, square

I am using square payment gateway and in **sandbox mode** If I use currency as USD, it works perfectly and give me response with transaction Id.

But If I use the currency as JPY (Japanese Yen) or other than USD, it gives me error as below.

**This business can only process payments in USD but amount was provided in JPY.**

I have googled it alot, but not found any solution, could someone please help me to sort it out.

Answer (score 2):

Square merchants can only process payments in the currency of the country of their account, So if you a have a US based account, you will only be able to take payments in US Dollars.

This help article might help: https://squareup.com/help/us/en/article/5415-can-i-accept-multiple-currencies-with-square

Comment: Yes, created a square up account by selecting country as Japan and then using the sandbox details of newly created account (location, secret and app id), it works!!